# Automapper: Update Only Few Column of Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orm, telerik, automapper

I am using Automapper with Telerik Open Access ORM.
Now my problem is there are 5 columns in my table `tblUser` like `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Username`, `Email` and `Password`.
Now when admin creates new user, it's password generated by some logic.

The problem is in update. Currently I show password field on user detail page with readonly textbox. Now I don't want to show password field. So is there anyway I skip password field while update?

I tried following but it throw error that password field as null.

```
var map = AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<UserDTO, TblUser>().ForSourceMember(x=>x.Password,y=>y.Ignore());
this.Update(entity);
this.Save();
return entity;

public void Update(T entity)
{
  dbContext.AttachCopy<U>(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<U>(entity));
}
```

**Error:**

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Password', table
>   'MyDatabase.dbo.tblUsers'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE
>   fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

I don't know how to update by skipping some fields.

For suppose I have 10 columns in insertion form and 5 columns in updation form for particular table, So while update I am taking other 5 column as hidden field to avoid error. But now I don't want to take other 5 fields as hidden. Isn't there any alternative exist?

Comment: Pass previous password while updating

Comment: @Justcode I don't want to pass it. So I need an alternative. For suppose I have 10 columns and form allows updation of only 5 columns, I am taking other 5 column as hidden field to avoid error. But now I don't want to take other 5 fields as hidden. Isn't there any alternative exist?

Comment: _column does not allow nulls_ so you dont want to insert in that table ?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal I want to insert, but at time of update i want to update only that fields which is updated. not others like password.

Comment: @DH__ don't think so. I think you should use query while updating
like if you have password filed and its getting null while updating then don't pass `update password=password`

Comment: You haven't shown your `Save()` method, but you can ignore a property(s) when saving as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734567/update-an-entity-using-entity-framework-while-ignoring-some-properties/25734683#25734683)

Answer (score 1):

You need to map to an existing entity:

```
var entity = dbContext.TblUsers.Find<TblUser>(dto.Id);
Mapper.Map<UserDTO, TblUser>(dto, entity);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```