# Validation failed for one or more entities. See EntityValidationErrors property for more details

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have the following two domain Models.

```
[Table("tblActual_AgencyProfile")]
public class AgencyModel
{
    public AgencyModel()
    {
        CategoryItemList = new List<CategoryModel>();
        user = new UserProfile();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UniqueURL { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ABN { get; set; }
    public string CAN { get; set; }
    public string PhotoURL { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Specialities { get; set; }
    public string LocationsServices { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ImportedDateTime { get; set; }
    public int? UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public UserProfile user { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CategoryModel> CategoryItemList { get; set; }
}


[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        Actual_Category_List = new List<CategoryViewModel>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfAttribute("UserType", "Agency")]
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CategoryViewModel> Actual_Category_List { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have an Update method in my Repository class

```
public void EditDetails(AgencyViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebScrapperDBContext contex = new WebScrapperDBContext())
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                AgencyModel agency = (from tb in contex.agencies where tb.ID == model.ID select tb).SingleOrDefault();
                agency.Address = model.Address;
                agency.Email = model.Email;
                agency.Fax = model.Fax;
                agency.LocationsServices = model.LocationsServices;
                agency.Name = model.Name;
                agency.Phone = model.Phone;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(agency.PhotoURL))
                    agency.PhotoURL = model.PhotoURL;
                agency.Specialities = model.Specialities;
                agency.Summary = model.Summary;

                agency.user.Address = model.Address;
                agency.user.AgencyName = model.Name;
                agency.user.EmailAddress = model.Email;
                agency.user.Fax = model.Fax;
                agency.user.Mobile = model.Mobile;
                agency.user.Phone = model.Phone;
                agency.user.PostCode = model.PostCode;
                agency.user.State = model.State;
                agency.user.Suburb = model.Suburb;

                contex.SaveChanges();

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I don't want to update all the fields in `UserProfile` (Ex: `FirstName`, `LastName`). When I run the `EditDetails()` method it throws an exception

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

This could be because I'm skipping some required fields in the domain model. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What does _See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details_ tell you about the error?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just checked the EntityValidationErrors. Exactly as I thought it's firing the validation errors for the required fields.

Comment: You probably need to have an `.Include(x => x.user)` in your query so the `user` property is populated with its existing values so you can pdate only what you need to.

Comment: Alternatively you could can exclude properties from updating as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734567/update-an-entity-using-entity-framework-while-ignoring-some-properties/25734683#25734683)

Comment: hi @StephenMuecke adding the .Include("user") worked thanks. If you could please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests the values of the properties of `user` are not being included in your the model you query is returning. You can force these to be populated by adding `.Include(x => x.user)` to your query. Then it is only necessary to update those properties you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configuration to ignore the validation when update. In your case you only need to update some properties instead of all.

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
context.SaveChanges();
```